# Comparing lists of ints in, while considering two ints not to be equal if repeated

Tags: c#, list, equality, value-type

I know this question has been reiterated multiple times, and I think this is straightforward when using lists of reference types. That is also what most questions talk about. When doing this with value types, I can't quite figure it out.

What I want do to is take an incoming request, and ensure that the request has *at least* the same numbers that are already present. Additional numbers are allowed, and the additional numbers in the request will be persisted. So if `[1,2]` is already persisted and the request contains `[1,2,3]`, `3` will be persisted. If the request contained only `1` or `2`, that would be invalid, and `[1,2]` would be valid and only the data that already existed would be returned.

The last case mentioned above I've implemented the following way:

```cs
Enumerable.SequenceEqual(existing.OrderBy(e => e), request.OrderBy(e => e));
```

When the lists aren't equal though, I want to treat each int in a list as if it was unique, but I can't figure out how to do this. In the following example, I would like the resulting list to be `[1, 4]`, but it ends up being `[4]` due to both the numbers `1` in the existing list are excluded due to being equal.

```cs
var existing = new List<int> { 1, 1, 2, 3, 4 };
var request = new List<int> { 1, 2, 3 };
existing.Except(request).ToList();
// 4
```

I have seen that `Except` accepts a [`IEqualityComparer`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.iequalitycomparer-1?view=net-6.0), but I stumble when trying to implement this for a value type and I don't know if this is the correct way to go.

Any help on how I should think when approaching this problem would be greatly appreciated. Efficiency is not that important, as the lists will not contain many elements at all.

Comment: As far as I understood we have two sources (incoming numbers, already persisted numbers) and one outcome (outgoing numbers). Could you write down a table or something similar describing the input lists and the expected outcome (e.g. `([1,2], [1,2,4]) -> [1,2,4]`? Maybe also as output `error` or something like this, if needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use regular `List<T>.Remove(T)`:

```
foreach(var e in existing)
{
    var actuallyExisted = request.Remove(e);
}
```

`actuallyExisted` will be false if it couldn't find `e` to remove. `request` will now contain all `int`s that weren't in existing.

Comment: I'm a bit mad at myself for staring blindly at utility functions when this solves my problem

Comment: Yeah not having to care about efficiency allows you to think of the old fashioned simple way of doing things...

Comment: I ended up going with something similar do this due to the simplicity and my overall skill level as well as my teams. Thank you!